# How to save historical data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to save historical data?

One way would be just using what I already have - `rails g scaffold value_history_datapoints item:references value:float` - then just iterate through items and create ValueHistoryDatapoint for each of the item.

BUT

The database is already clunky, has lots of datapoints, all of which must be kept, but there are some data that are already obsolete and useless (old `item`s that will never be used again, if nothing goes south).

Would it be better to somehow store all the data as json in the `item`'s model? Or is it just better to stick to relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the paper_trail gem? It creates a versions table that can store object data and changes for each CRUD operation.